# Button to slide to a specific section of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a button on my page lead to a session specified in the code, but I've tried several alternatives and none of them worked.

The code I'm currently using is this one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik">

<div>
<button id="comeceagora">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span> Comece Agora!
</button>
</div>

<style>
@media screen and (max-device-width : 1020px) {

button {
font-size: 15px!important;
animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glow{
  from {
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00f498, 0 0 15px #00f498, 0 0 25px #00bcaa, 0 0 50px #00f498;
  }
  
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00f498, 0 0 25px #00bcaa, 0 0 50px #00f498, 0 0 55px #00f498;
  }
}

}
div {
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
padding: 60px;
}

button {
 position: relative;
 padding: 1em 2em;
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid #303030;
 background: #000000;
 color: #00F498;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 25px;
 overflow: hidden;
transition: 0.2s;
border-radius: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: "Rubik";
font-weight: 900;
}

button:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00F498, 0 0 25px #00BCAA, 0 0 50px #00F498;
transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
button span {
position: absolute;
}
button span:nth-child(1) {
top: 0;
left: -100%;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(1) {
left: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
}
button span:nth-child(3) {
bottom: 0;
right: -100%;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(3) {
right: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
button span:nth-child(2) {
top: -100%;
right: 0;
width: 2px;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(2) {
top: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
transition-delay: 0.17s;
}
button span:nth-child(4) {
bottom: -100%;
left: 0;
width: 2px;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(4) {
bottom: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
transition-delay: 0.52s;
}
button:active {
background: #00F498;
background: linear-gradient(to top right, #00F498, #00BCAA);
color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px #00F498, 0 0 8px #00BCAA, 0 0 8px #00F498;
transition: 0.1s;
}
button:active span:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) {
transition: none;
transition-delay: none;
}
</style>

<script>
scrollTo = (element) => {
  window.scroll({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    left: 0,
    top: element.offsetTop
  });
  console
}

document.getElementById("comeceagora").addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollTo(document.getElementById("mercadoaudiovisual"));
});
</script>
```

The site was created in a site editor, so I don't have direct access to the HTML, but I do have access to the `<head>`.

As a base, the website editor support team helped me create a sticky side banner that leads to the footer of my page, the code used was this one:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(() => {
    const newLink = document.createElement('a')
    const text = document.createElement('p')
    const arrow = document.createElement('span')
    newLink.appendChild(arrow)
    newLink.appendChild(text)
    // Change this line to add text
    arrow.innerHTML = "←"
    text.innerText = "Formulário"
    newLink.onclick = function () {
      window.scroll(0,findPos(document.getElementById("download")));
    }
    newLink.classList.add('bannerSide')
    const bodyTag = document.querySelector('body')
    bodyTag.appendChild(newLink)
  }, 500)

function findPos(obj) {
    var curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return [curtop];
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  bannerSide.style.display = window.scrollY > 1000 ? 'flex' : 'none';
});
</script>
```

The code of this banner was inserted in the `<head>` of the site.

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, I'm trying to understand and evolve, but I still have difficulty, so please, I ask that the explanation be detailed so that I can understand what to do and so that I can learn to solve other things .

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Error message? Doesn’t scroll? Scrolls to wrong place?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining better.

Nothing happens when I click the button, it just ignores the code.

The side banner code created by the support team works, but I couldn't derive it for my button, even after spending all day trying.

Answer (score 3):

can you use `<a href="">` to scroll to a specific section or does it have to be done in `js`?

update:specifically wanted a button instead of `<a href="">`.
unfortunately i cant do it without some `js`. this is the best i can do to replicate `<a href="">` behavior's for a `button`

`onclick="window.location.href = '#comeceagora'">`

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

div {
  height: 120vh;
  width: 80vw;
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 1020px) {
  button {
    font-size: 15px!important;
    animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes glow {
    from {
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00f498, 0 0 15px #00f498, 0 0 25px #00bcaa, 0 0 50px #00f498;
    }
    to {
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00f498, 0 0 25px #00bcaa, 0 0 50px #00f498, 0 0 55px #00f498;
    }
  }
}

button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #303030;
  background: #000000;
  color: #00F498;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Rubik";
  font-weight: 900;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00F498, 0 0 25px #00BCAA, 0 0 50px #00F498;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

button span {
  position: absolute;
}

button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

button span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  right: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}

button span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.17s;
}

button span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #00F498);
}

button:hover span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
  transition-delay: 0.52s;
}

button:active {
  background: #00F498;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #00F498, #00BCAA);
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #00F498, 0 0 8px #00BCAA, 0 0 8px #00F498;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

button:active span:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) {
  transition: none;
  transition-delay: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<button onclick="window.location.href = '#comeceagora'">
        scroll to comeceagora
    </button>
<div></div>
<h1 id="comeceagora">comeceagora</h1>
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be done in JS, but it needs to be a button exactly like the one in my code.

I commented on JS because the button developed by the support team was made in JS.

Is it possible to make a button exactly the same way using <a href="">?

Comment: i updated the answer. hope i could help

Comment: Now for some reason the button disappears when clicking on it, I believe it has to do with the way the page code is built in this website builder (Zyro).

Anyway, thank you very much for your attention and dedication!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code does not work is because you did not declare `scrollTo` as a function. You also have a blank `console` statement that might be causing bugs. Try this script instead:

```
const scrollTo = (element) => {
  window.scroll({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    left: 0,
    top: element.offsetTop
  });
}

document.getElementById("comeceagora").addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollTo(document.getElementById("mercadoaudiovisual"));
});
```

Comment: I just tested it this way and it still doesn't take any action... do you have any idea what it could be?

Comment: @TyroneHirt take a look at this codesandbox file. I put your code in it and I added a ```<div id="mercadoaudiovisual"></div>``` and a spacer div. It works perfectly fine there. Maybe there is something else on your page you forgot to add.

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-northcutt-vfuexe?file=/index.html

Comment: Well, this code in theory should work perfectly, the issue is that apparently the code can't find the reference where it should scroll. If you can, take a look at my site and inspect the button, you will see that the code appears to be applied correctly, but not taking any action.

bldgprod.com.br

Anyway, thank you very much for your attention and dedication, I've been trying to solve this for days.

Comment: @TyroneHirt I think that your 'comece agora' button is missing an id attribute. That's why your javascript won't work. All you need to do is add ```id="comeceagora"``` to your button.

Answer (score 0):

> 2
>
> can you use  to scroll to a specific section or does it
> have to be done in js?
>
> update:specifically wanted a button instead of .
> unfortunately i cant do it without some js. this is the best i can do
> to replicate  behavior's for a button
>
> onclick="window.location.href = '#comeceagora'">

Using the button as the scroll anchor on the page worked, the code looked like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik">

<a href="#mercadoaudiovisual" target="_top">
<div>
<button id="comeceagora">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span> Comece Agora!
</button>
</div>
</a>

<style>
@media screen and (max-device-width : 1020px) {

button {
font-size: 15px!important;
animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
transition-delay: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glow{
  from {
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00f498, 0 0 15px #00f498, 0 0 25px #00bcaa, 0 0 50px #00f498;
  }
  
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00f498, 0 0 25px #00bcaa, 0 0 50px #00f498, 0 0 55px #00f498;
  }
}

}
div {
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
padding: 60px;
}

button {
 position: relative;
 padding: 1em 2em;
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid #303030;
 background: #000000;
 color: #00F498;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 25px;
 overflow: hidden;
transition: 0.2s;
border-radius: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: "Rubik";
font-weight: 900;
}

button:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00F498, 0 0 25px #00BCAA, 0 0 50px #00F498;
transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
button span {
position: absolute;
}
button span:nth-child(1) {
top: 0;
left: -100%;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(1) {
left: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
}
button span:nth-child(3) {
bottom: 0;
right: -100%;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(3) {
right: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
button span:nth-child(2) {
top: -100%;
right: 0;
width: 2px;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(2) {
top: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
transition-delay: 0.17s;
}
button span:nth-child(4) {
bottom: -100%;
left: 0;
width: 2px;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #00F498);
}
button:hover span:nth-child(4) {
bottom: 100%;
transition: 0.7s;
transition-delay: 0.52s;
}
button:active {
background: #00F498;
background: linear-gradient(to top right, #00F498, #00BCAA);
color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px #00F498, 0 0 8px #00BCAA, 0 0 8px #00F498;
transition: 0.1s;
}
button:active span:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(2) {
transition: none;
transition-delay: none;
}
</style>
```

But the problem is that this way the `#` is added to the page url and I wouldn't want that to happen... so I'm still racking my brains.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cf7oEpxETsc